# Что значит строка int guess = -1?

Tags: java

Вот мой код, взял с одной книги:

```
int num = (int)(Math.random()*101);
System.out.println("Guess a magic number from");

int guess = -1;
while(guess != num){
    System.out.print("\nEnter your guess: ");
    guess = input.nextInt();

    if(guess == num)
        System.out.println("You got it!");
    else if(guess > num)
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high!");
    else
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low!");
    }
```

Хочу узнать, что значит эта строка: `int guess = -1;`. Скажите, пожалуйста, что значит `-1` и зачем эта строка!

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В вашем конкретном случае значение -1 для переменной `guess` указано для того, чтобы на стадии определения входящих условий для цикла `while()` получить 100% вхождение в цикл. Если вы посмотрите на код выше, то увидите как генерируется значение для переменной `num`. Варианты получаются от 0 до 100 включительно. Следовательно, необходимо указать значение не входящее в этот диапазон. Вы можете с лёгкостью изменить -1 на любое в диапазоне от -2^31 до 2^31 и не входящее в диапазон генерируемых значений `num`. При этом логика работы вашего кода не изменится.

Comment: а почему именно до 101 если программа даёт числа до 100. И как я могу изменить -1 на 101......

Comment: Потому, что у вас цикл будет работать только при условии неравенства двух переменных. А если вы укажите `guess` переменную из диапазона генерируемых значений `num` то возможно совпадение значений и ваша программа проигнорирует цикл `while()` завершившись досрочно. Просто укажите вместо -1 другое значение вне диапазона 0 - 100 и всё. Оно может быть даже отрицательным. в диапазоне -2^31 до 2^31.

Comment: @user307320 Глядя на ваши вопросы и комментарии, я начинаю подозревать, что в этой книжке вы не попытались ничего почитать, а сразу кинулись пробовать код, который там написан. Не обижайтесь, но я бы сильно советовал читать и тот текст, который между кусками кода расположен, и пытаться его понять. Может еще и другие книжки почитать. Учиться программированию чисто "методом тыка" -- занятие не очень эффективное, и хороших результатов не дает. Если хотите быть профессиональным программистом, теорию понимать нужно, без этого никак

Comment: а вы не подумали то, что вдруг в этой книге нет этого объяснения, просто я только начал изучать java и я читаю книгу на англ.яз и всё понимаю просто именно в этом случае нет объяснения. А и ещё мне 13 лет

Comment: @user307320 как это коррелируется с моим ответом? Вы спросили - я ответил развёрнуто, что в принципе должно было бы понятно для человека имеющего базовые представлении о программировании. Если вам не нравится русло ответов на ваши ответы, то прилагайте к вопросам подпись "Антон, 13 лет". Это будет маркером для выбора определений при формировании ответа.

Comment: @Rootware это он пытался мне ответить. Кстати, простите, что я по неосторожности свой коммент насчет "читать больше" первоначально вам адресовал.

Comment: @user307320 Нет, мне не пришло в голову, что могут быть такие книги, где помещается код без объяснения. Мне такие не попадались. Ну что ж, тогда тем более почитайте другие книжки. А 13 лет -- это хорошо, я рад за вас.

Answer (score 1):

Первоначально генератор случайных чисел генерирует какое-то число в диапазоне от 0 до 100 включительно. Пользователю в цикле предлагается угадать это число. Если пользователь не угадал, то выводится соответствующая подсказка, а если угадал, то при следующей проверке условие цикла `guess != num` оказывается ложным и цикл прекращает выполнение.

В этой проверке и далее в цикле используется переменная `guess`. Всякая переменная к моменту ее использования должна иметь какое-то значение, определяемое ее инициализацией -- переменная не должна иметь неопределенного значения, иначе неопределенным будет поведение программы, что недопустимо. Язык Java просто не позволяет использовать неинициализированные переменные -- компилятор будет ругаться и не скомпилирует.

Так что переменной `guess` должно быть присвоено какое-то значение. Но чтобы цикл случайно не прекратил выполнение, не начав его, это значение должно быть таким, каким заведомо не может обладать к этому моменту переменная `num` -- то есть любым значением, меньшим, чем 0 или большим, чем 100. Любым. Автору понравилось -1, но вы точно с таким же успехом можете написать там 101 или 1234567890.

Comment: Правда, я должен оговориться, что `-1` предпочтительней в том смысле, что более прозрачно намекает на замысел автора -- большинство читателей поймет сразу, а какое-нибудь `74992` может погрузить читателя в глубокую задумчивость.